# jQuery trigger all instances on a nested form rails cocoon

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, cocoon-gem

I have a form with the following which are nested fields using cacoon

[image]

I have default fields and a conditional to show more fields if an option is selected ie. Rocket League like so

[image]

However, as you can see from the screenshot only one instance of a tournament standing is actually switching fields.

So my question is, how do I make every instance change?

Here is my code:

```
$(document).on("change", ".ts_select", function(event) {
  if (this.value == '1') {
    $('#default-fields').hide()
    $('#rocket-fields').show()
  } else {
    $('#default-fields').show()
    $('#rocket-fields').hide()
  }
})
```

```
<div id="default-fields" class="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-4">
    <%= render partial: "tournaments/fpartials/default", tournament: @tournament, locals: { f: f } %>
  </div>

  <div id="rocket-fields" class="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-4 hidden">
    <%= render partial: "tournaments/fpartials/rocket_league_fields", tournament: @tournament, locals: { f: f } %>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery selector you are using picks the first matching HTML element. So, in your case you are selecting the first `div`s with the IDs 'default-fields' and 'rocket-fields'.

Assuming all your team fields are just wrapped in `div`s with those IDs, you can use a different selector to find *all* instances:

```
$("[id='default-fields']").hide();
$("[id='default-fields']").show();
```

Check out the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) if you want to know more about how selectors work.

Comment: While this might visually work, using repeating html elements in a form with non-unique id's will cause problems (as id's are supposed to be unique).

Answer (score 1):

In html you have `id` and those are intended to be unique and present only once on a page, and you have `classes`. In your case you seem to be using an `id` for repeating elements.

While this might visually work, when posting the form you will then encounter problems (since when collecting the form-data only the assumed unique elements are collected).

So the best solution is to use classes instead, and adapt your code accordingly.

```
$(document).on("change", ".ts_select", function(event) {
  if (this.value == '1') {
    $('.default-fields').hide()
    $('.rocket-fields').show()
  } else {
    $('.default-fields').show()
    $('.rocket-fields').hide()
  }
})
```

Comment: Yes, this is a better answer than mine.